# Get the same part of the two arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, list

There are two large arrays a and b. How to get the same part gracefully?

```
a = [1, 4, 5, 9, 100000, ...]
b = [2, 5, 8, 9, 100001, ...]

len(a) > 100000000
len(b) > 100000000
```

How to get the value look like this:

```
[1 in b, 4 in b, 5 in b, 9 in b, 100000 in b, ... in b]
[False, False, True, True, False, ...]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [set intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))? Is there any importance to the *order* of the elements? Are there dupes in the array? Are the arrays sorted?

Comment: What is "the same part"?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 5, 9, 100000]
>>> b = [2, 5, 8, 9, 100001]
>>> b_set = set(b)
>>> [x in b for x in a]
[False, False, True, True, False]
```

`x in sequence` operation is a lot faster if you use `set` instead of `list`.

See [TimeComplexity - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 2):

If the arrays are sorted (Your example suggest they are) it can be done efficiently with linear time and constant memory, using two pointers and increasing the one pointing to the smallest element iteratively.

Python-like pseudo code:

```
i = 0
j = 0
res = []
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
   if a[i] == b[j]:
      res.append(True)
      i = i+1
      j = j+1
      continue
   if a[i] < b[j]:
      i = i + 1
      res.append(False)
   else:
      j = j + 1
while i < len(a):
    i = i + 1
    res.append(False)
```

PS note that the 'res' array used for output can be replaced to overwrite `a` in-place, since you write only after you have used the element (in `a`), and will never need it again.

Comment: @falsetru This is a pseudo code, since the question is tagged as 'algorithm', as well. let me clarify it. Feel free to edit any minor syntatic issue in the answer, this answer aims to show an efficient algorithmic solution and not "OTS python working code".

Comment: @falsetru If you regard to the missing "False" suffix - it can be very easily solved with very simple post-processing, and I do not consider it as an algorithmic problem. Again, this answer is focusing on how to do it in the most efficient way possible in terms of both time and space complexity. I'll add that post-processing anyway, thanks for commenting.

Comment: set(uids).intersection(set(spams))

2.86s user 0.30s system 82% cpu 3.837 total

Comment: b = set(b)
return [uid in b for uid in a]

2.28s user 0.32s system 77% cpu 3.344 total

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same part of each array, you can doing simply : set(a).intersection(set(b))